# Android: Issue with Switch in Custom List Adaptor

Tags: android, listview, debugging, object, switch-statement

I have a templates page and on this page I can add and delete templates giving them names and descriptions.

Each template is an object consisting of  name, description, power and enable.

- Clicking on a template loads another list view with options.
- Each option is an instance of an object called Option.
- Each option has a Switch which I can toggle.
- When I then save the template, I update in the database values with regards to whether those switches were on or off.

SO jumping right to the problem.

We can move past the first template list view but onto the next one, the options list view.

This list view just contains 2 options, Power and Enable. Here is how I create these options.

```
TEMPLATEPOWER("Turn on device", "Switching this will turn on and off the fitting"),
TEMPLATEENABLED("Enable Device", "Switching this will enable and disable the device");
```

- In simple terms, it is just an enum
- I then have a Control options which handles this enum.

Control file:

```
  public ArrayList<Option> populateTemplateActions() {
    actions.add(Option.TEMPLATEPOWER);
    actions.add(Option.TEMPLATEENABLED);
    return actions;
}
```

Now for setting the list view. To do this:

- I create an array of options and call the above method to add these enum objects to the array
- I then pass this array onto the adaptor.
- I also pass the fragment over, as I need to be able to set the Template object in the fragment.

Populating the array:

```
templateOptions = control.populateTemplateActions();
```

Creating the list view:

```
adapter = new TemplateOptionAdapter(
                getActivity(), templateOptions, template, ViewTemplate.this);
        templateOptionsView.setAdapter(adapter);

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Once I am in the adaptor I set the text views and the switch. I then deal with setting the power and enable options by using change listener on the switch.

- I firstly check the option row object to see if it is a) Power or b) Enable.
- I then Set it to checked or not checked.
- The listener then listens for changes, and when the changes happen sets the methods accordingly.
- I then pass this changed object back into the fragment which contains the list view so I can insert the values into the database.

To be thorough, I will post the entire adaptor code below:

```
public class TemplateOptionAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Option> templateList;
    private String name;
    private Template template;
    private Boolean checked;
    int power;
    int enable;
    Option option;
    ViewTemplate viewTemplate;

    public TemplateOptionAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Option> list, Template template, ViewTemplate viewTemplate) {
        this.context = context;
        templateList = list;
        this.template = template;
        this.viewTemplate = viewTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return templateList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return templateList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
        option = templateList.get(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.template_option_view_row, null);

        }
        TextView templateName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.option_name);
        TextView templateDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.option_info);
        SwitchCompat optionSwitch = convertView.findViewById(R.id.optionSwitch);

        name = option.getOptionName();
        String description = option.getOptionDesc();

        templateName.setText(name);
        templateDesc.setText(description);

        power = template.getTemplatePower();
        enable = template.getTemplateStatus();

        // Sets switches to their database values
        switch (option) {
            case TEMPLATEPOWER:
                if (power == 0) {
                    optionSwitch.setChecked(false);
                }

                else {
                    optionSwitch.setChecked(true);
                }
                break;
            case TEMPLATEENABLED:
                if (enable == 0) {
                    optionSwitch.setChecked(false);
                }

                else {
                    optionSwitch.setChecked(true);
                }
                break;
        }

        // Monitors changing of switches and sets objects to be saved.

        optionSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    checked = true;
                    switch (option) {
                        case TEMPLATEPOWER:
                            template.setTemplatePower(1);
                            Log.i("power", "power setting to 1" + "");
                            Log.i("enable", "enable dosnt change" + "");
                            break;
                        case TEMPLATEENABLED:
                            template.setTemplateStatus(1);
                            Log.i("power", "power dosnt change" + "");
                            Log.i("enable", "enable setting to 1" + "");
                            break;
                    }
                } else {
                    checked = false;
                    switch (option) {
                        case TEMPLATEPOWER:
                            template.setTemplatePower(0);
                            Log.i("power", "power setting to 1" + "");
                            Log.i("enable", "enable dosnt change" + "");
                            break;
                        case TEMPLATEENABLED:
                            template.setTemplateStatus(0);
                            Log.i("power", "power dosnt change" + "");
                            Log.i("enable", "enable setting to 0" + "");
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

        });

        viewTemplate.setTemplate(template);
        return convertView;
    }
```

Wow, if you are still with me great, thanks!

Okay so the problem at hand.

When I am back in the fragment containing the list view, when I click a button to save:
No matter which I toggle, power or enable, the enable option is the only value that changes. For example:

- If I set the power to on, enable is set to on instead.
- If I set power to off, enable is set off instead.

So in my switch statement, it appears the case TEMPLATEPOWER is never seen, even though it is one of the options.

I am a rookie android developer, I am sure this a flaw in my logic, I just cannot see where!

Any advice would be amazing, Thanks!

If you need any more clarification, just ask :)

Comment: Another note I have just found. If I switch the two options around, the problem still exists but the problem is the other way. It is only selecting the final option in the list....

Answer (score 0):

There may be better ways to perform this whole function, but after hours of trying to fix my case, I have managed something.

Where I was getting the object option with the list position in the adapter, I should have set it to final, as it kept changing value.

I changed:

```
option = templateList.get(position);
```

To:

```
final Option option = templateList.get(position);
```